# React - Module not found - As if the directory didn't exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a beginner in react and I'm not able to resolve this error at all. I have no idea what to do, I've tried to recreate, look for an answer and this error always appears as if the directory did not exist.

Can someone help me?

Error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/MenuComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/DishDetailComponent'
```

MenuComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './components/DishDetailComponent';

class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        };
    }
    ...
}

export default Menu;
```

DishDetailComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DishDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Folder
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axDUn.png)

Comment: Not familiar with react but your import looks odd. I would think you need to use `../components/DishDetailComponent` or `./DishDetailComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Paths are relative from the module where they are imported. Both your files are in the `components` directory, but `MenuComponent.js` is trying to import from `./components/DishDetailComponent`, which actually results in `./components/components/DishDetailComponent`.

Change your import to be just `./DishDetailComponent` and it should be fine.

Comment: No probs! Please mark this as the answer if this solved the problem for you :)